# Как создать проект в Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Как создать проект в Visual Studio for Mac для разработки кроссплатформенного десктопного приложения(на C#) с помощью Mono?

Я скачал VS отсюда - https://www.monodevelop.com/download/

Скачал Mono отсюда - https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

Но всё что у меня есть это создание библиотеки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слева на вашем скрине, чуть ниже библиотек идет .NET Core приложение

Comment: Это разве не веб?

Comment: официального способа разработки кросплатформенного десктопного приложения(на C#) от MS нет в природе. Есть [ещё не вышедшая Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia). По поводу mono - я не думаю (но может я и не прав), что VS имеет с ним интеграцию. Раншье авторы, что писали на mono, использовали monodevelop для этого. Но я на mono не пишу, потому ничего более определенного сказать не могу.